# Stop sqlite resetting autoincrement on primary key

Tags: sqlite

If you delete the rows on the end of the table, the autoincrement resets:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
...
sqlite> SELECT * FROM my_table;
1
2
3
sqlite> DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 3;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM my_table;
1
2
sqlite> INSERT INTO my_table DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM my_table;
1
2
3
```

I want the last command to return

```
1
2
4
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get such behaviour if you defile primary key as AUTOINCREMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ..
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/U0Y3H-9w

Docs on AUTOINCREMENT: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

*the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.*